# Ampersand in query string messing up simple mailto of a link in the body

Tags: c#, email, mailto

I'm trying to do a simple mailto inside my C# ASP.Net web app.

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:?subject=View Rig Map&body=" + url);
```

However if the url has a query string with an ampersand (&) separating the name-value pairs like so "http://localhost:51771/MuseumViewer.aspx?MuseumIDs=3301&CountryIDs=1" the link it cut off in the body of the email at "http://localhost:51771/MuseumViewer.aspx?MuseumIDs=3301."

I don't really want to do anything fancy because all I need to do is have the link in the body of the email. Can anyone help me with this? Would it work if I put the mailto on the client side?

**UPDATE with SOLUTION**
I'm having a tough time deciding on who to pick as the answer but here is the solution I used:

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string link = Server.UrlEncode(url);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:?subject=View Rig Map&body=" + link);
```

Comment: not my area - but can you use &amp; ?

Comment: I tried doing something like that but it didn't seem to like it. I did: url.Replace("&", "&amp") but after following it through the debugger. It didn't change the ampersand in the string.

Comment: Did you just do url.Replace("&","&amp;") or did you assign it back to url like url = url.Replace("&","&amp;")

Comment: I just did url.Replace("&","&amp;"). Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

%26 is the URL escape code for an ampersand. Try running UrlEncode() on the url.

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to System.Web to your project.

Use the below lines in your app

```
string url = "http://localhost:51771/MuseumViewer.aspx?MuseumIDs=3301&CountryIDs=1";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:?subject=View Rig Map&body=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(url));
```

Comment: +1 because this also works. I saw Eli's answer first and it worked.